# Parsing result of Diff in Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to compare two files and see if they are the same or not in my shell script, my way is:

```
diff_output=`diff ${dest_file} ${source_file}`

if [ some_other_condition -o ${diff_output} -o some_other_condition2 ]
then
....
fi
```

Basically, if they are the same ${diff_output} should contain nothing and the above test would evaluate to true.

But when I run my script, it says
[: too many arguments

On the if [....] line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you care about what the actual differences are, or just whether the files are different? If it's the latter you don't need to parse the output; you can check the exit code instead.

```
if diff -q "$source_file" "$dest_file" > /dev/null; then
    : # files are the same
else
    : # files are different
fi
```

Or use `cmp` which is more efficient:

```
if cmp -s "$source_file" "$dest_file"; then
    : # files are the same
else
    : # files are different
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an option provided precisely for doing this: `-q` (or `--quiet`). It tells diff to just let the exit code indicate whether the files were identical. That way you can do this:

```
if diff -q "$dest_file" "$source_file"; then
    # files are identical
else
    # files differ
fi
```

or if you want to swap the two clauses:

```
if ! diff -q "$dest_file" "$source_file"; then
    # files differ
else
    # files are identical
fi
```

If you really wanted to do it your way (i.e. you need the output) you should do this:

```
if [ -n "$diff_output" -o ... ]; then
    ...
fi
```

`-n` means "test if the following string is non-empty. You also have to surround it with quotes, so that if it's empty, the test still has a string there - you're getting your error because your test evaluates to `some_other_condition -o -o some_other_condition2`, which as you can see isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

**diff** is for comparing files *line by line* for  processing the differences  tool like **patch** . If you just want to check if they are different, you should use **cmp**:

```
cmp --quiet $source_file $dest_file || echo Different
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diff $FILE $FILE2
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
echo “TWO FILES ARE SAME”
else
echo “TWO FILES ARE SOMEWHAT DIFFERENT”
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `Check files for difference in bash`

```
source_file=abc.txt
dest_file=xyz.txt

if [[ -z $(sdiff -s $dest_file $source_file) ]]; then  

   echo "Files are same"

else

   echo "Files are different"

fi
```

#### `Code tested on RHEL/CentOS Linux (6.X and 7.X)`